# line radchart is displaying values for both lines

Tags: collections, telerik, charts, multiline

I have a radchart that is supposed to display two lines with separate Y values, but when it loads it displays two lines, but they both have Y values that they are supposed to display and the Y values of the other line in the chart
ie: 
(Data set 1: 1,2,6,9)
(Data set 2: 1,4,6,7)
(Lines display like:   1-1-2-4-6-6-9-7 and 1-1-2-4-6-6-9-7)

my series mapping looks like this:

```
<telerik:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Line Series 1" >
    <telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
        <telerik:StackedLineSeriesDefinition />
    </telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
        <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="LineYValue" DataPointMember="YValue" />
    </telerik:SeriesMapping>

    <telerik:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Line Series 2" >
        <telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
            <telerik:StackedLineSeriesDefinition />
        </telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
        <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="LineYValue" DataPointMember="YValue" />
    </telerik:SeriesMapping>
</telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
```

and in my ViewModel I have the data loaded like so

```
if (salesAndQtyByHour != null)
{
    STUFF.ChartModels.Charts tempChart1 = new ODA.ChartModels.Charts() { ChartTitle = "Sales And Quantity By Hour" };
    foreach (var item in salesAndQtyByHour)
    {
        tempChart1.myCharts.Add(new STUFF.ChartModels.Chart() { LineName = "Quantity", LineXValue = item.MilitaryTime, LineYValue = item.QtyOfItems });
        tempChart1.myCharts.Add(new STUFF.ChartModels.Chart() { LineName = "Basket", LineXValue = item.MilitaryTime, LineYValue = item.Basket });
    }
    SalesAndQtyByHour = tempChart1;
}
```

I'm pretty sure its the CollectionIndex, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case, I'm relatively new to this job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ItemsSource property of the SeriesMapping object. You can send each individual dataset to the corresponding SeriesMapping. Article:
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchart-populating-with-data-series-mapping-items-source.html